# AVSpeechSynthesizer utterance to audio file

Tags: ios, ios7, avspeechsynthesizer

I'm using AVSpeechSynthesizer in my app and I'm looking to save the spoken text to an audio file or AVAsset. I went through Apple's docs and didn't see anything but figured I'd post a question to make sure. Below is my current code.

```
AVSpeechUtterance * utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:textView.text];
float rate = [speedSlider value]/1.5;
utterance.rate =  rate;
[speechSynthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
```

Comment: This API is new, and so it may lack certain features that may be added on later. Maybe look into a way of recording any audio that is playing?

Comment: Yeah I set up an AVAudioRecoder already but just wanted to see if there was a cleaner solution

Comment: Did you find a suitable solution for this problem? I'm looking to build something similar.

Comment: I am looking for the solution too.  Please let me know if you found one.  Thanks

Comment: I've also tried the AVAudioRecorder approach, however, it's not suitable, since the noise from outside is also captured.  I hope there's a more relevant approach on how to achieve this. That you can silently create the audio file from AVSpeechUtterance.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to record audio generated by *your* app (not from other apps). Although `AVSpeech` does not provide an API to save the generated audio, Apple has other APIs that can do the job. The solution is probably not as clean as you would like, but it should work.

Apple provides a framework called the [Audio Unit Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioUnit/Reference/AudioUnit_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007295) to manage advanced audio processing and recording. This is the only Framework in the iOS SDK (to my knowledge) that can play and record audio simultaneously. The [Audio Unit Hosting Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitHostingGuide_iOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) looks promising, and so does the [Audio Mixer Sample App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MixerHost/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010210-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2).

Note: I have not tried using the Audio Unit Framework with AVSpeechSynthesizer (it may or may not work). However, considering AVSpeechSynthesizer plays nice with CoreAudio then it is more than likely it will work with AudioUnits.

---

If the above solution does not work, then a simple workaround may do the trick. `AVSpeechSynthesizer` does not require any network connection to properly function, so in many cases you may not *need* to save the audio. Instead you could save the text for later using NSFileManager:

```
NSString *textToSynthesize = @"Just what do you think you are doing, Dave?";

NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths firstObject];

[textToSynthesize writeToFile:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"synthText.txt"] atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

When you are ready to synthesize the text, just read it from the file and plug it back into the `AVSpeechSynthesizer`. I do realize that this solution will not work or apply in all cases (e.g. if you need to send the audio file to someone).

---

Those are just a few possible solutions for the issue, both of which are workarounds and may or may not work depending on your specific scenario. YMMV. Good luck!

Comment: The first part of Sam's answer is good - Apple does provide resources to use Audio Units and an audio processing queue to manipulate, record and play audio, however it's very complicated to use and may be more time than you're willing to invest. However if you feel that this is your only option, you should look into The Amazing Audio Engine, which provides an easier to use interface to Apple's Core Audio framework.

[Amazing Audio Engine Website](http://theamazingaudioengine.com/)