# How to record the output voice of the AVSpeechSynthesizer?

Tags: ios, text-to-speech, avspeechsynthesizer

Is there any way to record/keep the voice of the AVSpeechSynthesizer before it being played and then applying some effects to it(as a voice file)? If not, do you know any open source alternative which we can do such thing with it's output voice? Thanks.

Comment: try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20601824/avspeechsynthesizer-utterance-to-audio-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AVSpeechSynthesizer output as file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25965601/avspeechsynthesizer-output-as-file)