# AVSpeechSynthesizer to AVAudioUnitReverb

Tags: avaudioengine, avspeechsynthesizer

Using the default AVSpeechSynthesizer source code from Apple, is it possible to route the audio through an AVAduioUnit?

The idea is to get text-to-speech running through the AVAudioEngine.

Comment: maybe?  I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20601824/avspeechsynthesizer-utterance-to-audio-file

Answer (score 0):

We just introduced a speech synthesizer into AudioKit, which can route the speech through any of our numerous processors, or a custom one of your own. One caveat - its currently only on macOS, not iOS.

https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/tree/master/Examples/macOS/SpeechSynthesizer